# How can I Merge two python code by using tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

How can use two python code in one program by using tkinter, when press the first button it run my first project when press second button it run my second project?

Comment: can you elaborate?

Comment: You can bind functions to button presses. So why don't you try this and report back?

Comment: Wrap your projects' entry points into functions so you can import them without side effects, then call those entry point functions via those buttons.

Comment: What did you try? Please, spend some time reading ["How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You will get better results by following the tips in those articles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace Path Of Your Project File :

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import os

win=tk.Tk()

def run1():
    os.system("python path to 1.py")
def run2():
    os.system("python path to 2.py")

button1=ttk.Button(win,text="Run 1.py",command=run1)
button2=ttk.Button(win,text="Run 2.py",command=run2)
button1.pack()
button2.pack()

win.mainloop()
```

1.py :

```
print("Hello ! from 1.py")
```

2.py :

```
print("Hello ! from 2.py")
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to run 2 programs at one time by pressing 1 button, right?

Create 2 separate programs.
Then here's the final code:

```
from tkinter import Tk
from tkinter.ttk import Button
import os

root = Tk() # Creating the main window
root.title("Whatever you want")
root.geometry("300x200")

def open_files():    # function to run the apps/programs/files
    os.startfile("file1.py")
    os.startfile("file2.py")

open_b = Button(root, text="Open files", command=open_files)    # Creating the button
open_b.pack(pady=20)

root.mainloop()
```